# Use `unittest` to verify that the `exit` function was called

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, exit

I defined a very simple configuration manager (parses config files and verifies that certain keys exist in them) and now I'm writing some tests for it.

In many cases where the config file is is invalid, I want the configuration handler to call `exit()`. Is there some way I can write tests to ensure that `exit` was called and still continue testing? Can I perhaps, for a testing environment only, "mock" the `exit` function?

I am using Python 2.7 and `unittest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.exit()` raises the `SystemExit` exception, which should be caught by the unittest framework.  So you can check that `SystemExit` is raised for those test cases.

Example, `exit_test.py`:

```
import sys
import unittest


def func():
    sys.exit()


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_func(self):
        self.assertRaises(SystemExit, func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Run:

```
$ python exit_test.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```